# What to do when I disagree with a mod about a question marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

Here's the question: [How long is raw (unrendered) beef suet is good for in the fridge?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/99787/how-long-is-raw-unrendered-beef-suet-is-good-for-in-the-fridge)

Please read it full.

The mod closed it as duplicate. But that question has no answer whatsover. In the comments she says "the FDA does not issue different guidelines for different parts of the cow.". However, I'm looking for answers based on people's actual experience, and I don't particularly care what the Food and Drug Administration of a country says, which by the way does differ based on which kind of meat we are talking about (eg: ground beef is lower duration).

Someone, please, reopen that question. By closing it as duplicate you are preventing other people from providing the answer!

Comment: rumtscho uses she/her pronouns, and while it's fine to disagree with moderators, it's not okay to be hostile.

Comment: I usually won't write on a question discussing my own actions as a moderator, as that's for others to judge. But I want to address an important point you are making in your question. You say "I don't care what the [FDA] says" - that's something we commonly see in users, but we cannot accomodate such a request. All questions on this site are required to be objectively answerable. For food safety questions, one can either want to listen to personal opinion, or to published guidelines. Since the first is terribly subjective, we do not accept that interpretation on the site and always...

Comment: ... treat questions on food safety as a request for citing FDA guidelines (or those of other countries' food authorities, but we don't have users who know and cite those in practice). Any answers that state personal opinion are deleted. This is a policy which has been applied for many years now and has nothing to do with your particular question. So, if your question gets reopened, all you'll get as answers will be the FDA guidelines.

Comment: Considering your request for individual data, you may want to check out [this Q/A](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64171/is-it-true-cooked-food-cannot-be-left-in-room-temperature-for-longer-than-4-hour).

Comment: @rumtscho I was not being hostile; you are projecting your feelings onto me. Do you really find it hard to deal with fellow human beings taking only what they actually write into account?

Comment: I never tried to attribute any specific feelings to you, and do not perceive you as hostile. The "I don't care" statement is something I quote from your own question above, everything else is an attempt to explain site policy.

Comment: @rumtscho I suspect you are not the actual addressee - see Cascabel’s comment, concerning the original version of the question, prior to the edit.

Comment: Oops yea, I meant to address @Cascabel. You should not project your feelings onto your fellow human beings. Don't accuse others without pointing out the exact words that indicated hostility.

Comment: It is actually the task of a moderator to point out when a post’s phrasing is not following the guidelines of the Code of Conduct. In this case, the parts in question were removed by edit, as it’s standard procedure. If you would like to re-read your original version, you can access the edit history.

Comment: When I mention hostility, I'm referring to the contents of your post. Whatever your intentions may have been, your post crossed a line, so I simply did what was necessary.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first part of the question:

If you disagree with a closure, first follow the procedure described in our [help](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions). If you think it’s necessary you can post on Seasoned Advice Meta, explaining why you disagree. In both cases,  you then leave it to the community.

So let me be the first answer to explain why I fully agree with the closure - which brings us exactly to the second part of your question, namely that you don’t want the recommendation of the FDA or similar authorities and expect answers citing individual user experiences instead.

I am afraid this isn’t going to happen. The reason is the community agreement that we will only accept questions in food *safety* and you need to understand the difference between

- food that is **spoiled** (sometimes easily recognizable, but actually not always) and
- food that is **unsafe**, which means that there’s a reasonably high risk that it harbors an amount of bacteria that can make a consumer sick. This doesn’t mean that it actually spoiled, but that it simply isn’t guaranteed safe.

The latter can be determined by scientific experiments and indeed organizations like the FDA perform them which leads to the published threshold values for how long different food items can be stored at what temperatures. We don’t take the FDA values as gospel, but if you do some research, you will find that other reliable sources published comparable recommendations.

On this site, we have the well-being of all users in mind. So we can not accept individual anecdotes (and every answer of “I did X and was fine” invariably falls into that category) over scientific data. While no longer safe doesn’t automatically equal spoiled, we are not going to put anyone - including the weakest members of society like children - at risk.

And therefore, your post is a duplicate of the generic post on shelf life, where you can find a value for the suet you were asking about. (Btw, the times for minced meat are shorter because the processing step leads to a greater surface area and a possible transfer of surface bacteria to the interior.)

———————-

An additional note re. your claim that a single moderator was dealing with your posts and possibly making unilateral decisions. I can assure you that this is not the case. Your posts and the flags you raised were handled by *different* mods and we do agree on the correct procedure here.

Comment: I should have been more precise. The FDA does _not_ say anything specifically about fridge lifetime of suet. And the answer you linked to does not mention anything about suet either. For dramatic effect I could say that the moderator was lying, but instead of doing that I'm simply asking for a reference to where actually the FDA states anything about suet. The whole point of asking it in Stackexchange is so that someone can provide that reference, but instead you are closing the question.

Comment: There is no ignorance on the mod’s nor the generic Q/A side. Meat is typically classified as “protein”. Yes, including very, very fatty pieces of meats. So the suet does indeed fall into the “uncooked meat” category with a fridge storage time of 3-5 days. **The generic Q/A clearly states that number *and* you were given this explanation before in comments under your question.**